# php executes only one ajax call at time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

i have ajax calls to server, that returns processed json data. To speed things up i need them to be executed at the same time.

**Problem:**
I get executed and returned only one request at the time
[image: Ajax calls]

As you can see, there is response times that almost doubles each time, but data sent always the same. If i understand corectly, there must be all call times e.g. 15,47s.
aJax:

```
$.each([76, 76, 76, 76], function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?r=report/generateReport',
         type: 'post',
         dataType: 'json',
         data:{ ... },
         async: true,
         success: function(json){
             ....
         }
      });

    console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: Looks like single threaded execution on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use sessions? Then it's the session locking. Call `session_write_close()` as soon as possible.